# Sony xperia z2 how to factory reset

Tags: factory-reset, hard-reset

i have a sony xperia z2 d6503 running on android 6.0.1
and has two users. ive forgotten the pin for the owner account and using the guest account i created for my kids
now i want to factory reset but havent been successful. please help

Comment: You have to flash the phone. Sony devices do not support hard resetting. Download the ftf file and use Androxyl Flashtool to flash the phone.

Comment: @esQmo Where'd you get this? Sony phones do support hard resetting.

Comment: They don't. And you're fooling people with the buttons combo.

Comment: @esQmo They do. From personal experience.  Not sure whether I should upload a video then to show you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume since you were willing to do a factory reset, that you're also willing to forego all the data currently possessed on your phone.

You could hard reset your device through the following method.

**Procedure**

1. Switch your phone off.
2. Wait at least 15 seconds before simultaneously pressing the volume down key + power button until the device vibrates.
3. Through use of you're volume up and down keys, highlight factory reset and hit the power button.

> **Ensure that you have enough battery charge** to do this(recommended 40% and above; your battery shouldn't also drain fast). Failure to do so could result in soft bricking your phone rendering it useless.

This will reset your phone back to its original state.

**Update**
The following links provide methods used to hard reset the z2 that I have already outlined in my answer.
[Hard reset z2 verizon](https://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-129435/) 
[Hard Reset z2](http://rechargeboom.com/hard-reset/sony-xperia-hard-reset/sony-xperia-z2-hard-reset-password-recovery-factory-reset/)

As has been raised in the comments, that Sony devices do not support hard resetting. The above links provide those methods while I have indeed myself been able to reset sony xperia z4 and the c5. [Attached](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.hardreset.info/devices/sony/sony-xperia-z-l36a-c6606/&ved=0ahUKEwjR_9GhpLnQAhUDfRoKHdM-DAAQFggmMAI&usg=AFQjCNFwX8Pjy2PTKVs3z_ExkkIuuOHzwg&sig2=Ay0lzbxLSzHIbP2zJbJLfA) is the method I used to hard reset those devices.

Comment: Did you, I mean, personally test this?

Comment: @esQmo Yes I did. On the xperia z4 also on c5. Don't understand why you'd downvote me without enquiring or confirming first.

Comment: Can you link a reference? Cause the only way to do a factory reset is by flashing the whole phone or simply the userdata partition.

Comment: @esQmo the Z4 and c5 have different procedures other than this since you wait for the device led to come on then tap either volume button severally.

Comment: Try adding a source by editing your answer.

Comment: @esQmo They've been added. I'd advise you to read on why recovery mode/ bootable dedicated partitions exists on android devices.